# This prepared statement Update query isn't working ... why?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, prepared-statement

```
$query="UPDATE `db`.`tb` SET `colA` = ?, `colB` = ?, `colC` = ?, `colD` = ?, `colE` = ?, `colF` = ?, `colG` = ? WHERE `tb`.`colA` = ? AND month(date)= ?;";
$stmt = $web_dbi->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $colA_PHPvar, $colB_PHPvar, $colC_PHPvar, $colD_PHPvar, $colE_PHPvar, $colF_PHPvar, $colG_PHPvar, $colA_PHPvar, $colB_PHPvar);
$stmt->execute();
```

Additional information:

1. `date` is the name of a column in `db`.`tb` ...
2. This query works when I remove the `AND month(date)= ?` from the Where clause and it's corresponding `?` variable ...

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  If you mean that no rows are updated, the most likely explanation is that no rows have the month in question.

Comment: AJAX call returns success message, database record isn't updated ...

Comment: ...maybe an uncommitted sql transaction?

Comment: `date` is a keyword in MySQL (and many other RDBMSs as well). As such, it's a bad idea for a column name. You can try using back ticks around the column name and that might fix the issue.

Comment: figured it out ... I was passing a date variable from via AJAX that was formatted as the numerical representation of the month (i.e. January=1 ...), and included the `date` column as a column to update (formatted as a date in MySQL), when really I only needed the `date` column in the Where clause (the numerical representation of month successfully matched month(`date`) in database and updated other fields and correctly format errored while updating `date` (`date` in database is simply the first of the month (m-1-yyyy) (which can stay the same here) ... I appreciate the help ... stay classy ...

Comment: @TomH . . . `date` *is* a bad choice for a column name.  But, it is a keyword and not a reserved word, so no backticks are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out ... I was passing a date variable via AJAX that was formatted as the numerical representation of the month (i.e. January=1 ...), and included the `date` column as a column to update (formatted as a date in MySQL)(m-1-yyyy), when really I only needed the `date` column in the Where clause (the numerical representation of month successfully matched month(`date`) in database and updated other fields, and correctly format errored while updating `date` (`date` in database is simply the first of the month (m-1-yyyy)) (which can stay the same here) ...

```
$query="UPDATE `db`.`tb` SET `colA` = ?, `colB` = ?, `colC` = ?, `colE` = ?, `colF` = ?, `colG` = ? WHERE `tb`.`colA` = ? AND month(date)= ?;";
$stmt = $web_dbi->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $colA_PHPvar, $colB_PHPvar, $colC_PHPvar, $colE_PHPvar, $colF_PHPvar, $colG_PHPvar, $colA_PHPvar, $colB_PHPvar);
$stmt->execute();
```

(`colD` and `$colD_PHPvar` were the date variable being passed via AJAX as a numerical representation of the month (i.e. January=1 ...) ...